# How to get last inserted record ID using C# and DB2

Tags: c#, db2

Using C# with DB2 in my application. Want to get last inserted record id to pass in another SQL statement. Please find below my code:

```
        DB2Command myCommand = new DB2Command();
    DB2Connection con = new DB2Connection(ConnectionString);
    myCommand.Connection = con;

    try
    {
        myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        myCommand.CommandText = "SELECT ID FROM FINAL TABLE (INSERT INTO MyTable(col1,col2) "
               + " VALUES (val1, val2)";


        con.Open();
        lastInstertedId = myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

But it is throwing error:

> The operation failed because the operation is not supported with the type of the specified table.

If I change CommandText to below given line then it works fine but retorns 1(effected row number).

```
myCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO MyTable(col1,col2) "
           + " VALUES (val1, val2)";
```

Please let me know, how to get last inserted record Id.

Comment: That at least _looks_ correct.  What's your exact platform/version of DB2, please?  (Although I'm assuming recent-ish LUW).  It's complaining about the table type... what's the actual underlying type of `MyTable`?  Do you have the actual error code, not just the text message?

Answer (score 0):

i think the sql should be:

```
 myCommand.CommandText = "SELECT ID FROM NEW TABLE (INSERT INTO MyTable(col1,col2) "
           + " VALUES (val1, val2)";
```

> What we did in DB2 was to simply expose the trigger transition table NEW TABLE in the from-clause.
>   So, when you put an INSERT statement into the from clause that insert statement is executed and in the process a transition table is produced.
>   That transition table, which includes all the modifications of any before triggers can then be queried.

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/SQLTips4DB2LUW/entry/select_from_insert?lang=en

*notice the `FINAL` has been replaced by `NEW`*

Comment: ...as near as I know, [`FINAL TABLE` is the proper syntax here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_11.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sql_tablereference.html), and not `NEW TABLE`...

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse
If it's DB2 for LUW, then both are acceptable, but there is some difference. See the description of [data-change-table-reference](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0059206.html?view=kc#r0059206__dctr)

Comment: Getting same issue with "New" as well. :(

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like below.

```
DB2Command myCommand = new DB2Command();
DB2Connection con = new DB2Connection(ConnectionString);
myCommand.Connection = con;

try
{
    myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    myCommand.CommandText = "SELECT ID FROM FINAL TABLE (INSERT INTO MyTable(col1,col2) "
           + " VALUES (val1, val2)";
    Integer lastInstertedId = (Integer)myCommand.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume your table is `ORGANIZE BY COLUMN`. Those tables do not currently support  [data-change-table-reference](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0059206.html?view=kc#r0059206__dctr)

```
$ db2 "create table m(i int) organize by column"
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.

$ db2 "select * from final table(insert into m values 1)"
SQL1667N  The operation failed because the operation is not supported with the 
type of the specified table.  Specified table: "PAUL.M".  Table type: 
"ORGANIZE BY COLUMN".  Operation: "FINAL|NEW|OLD TABLE".  SQLSTATE=42858

$ db2 "create table m(i int) organize by row"
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.

$ db2 "select * from final table(insert into m values 1)"

I          
-----------
          1

  1 record(s) selected.
```